# Messagebox displaying too early - C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, messagebox

I am just starting off with the world of programming C#, and have come across a small glitch in my code which causes the design to be ruined.

For some reason, when I am trying change the text in a textbox, it does not visually change until a messagebox has been displayed, which is underneath the code to change the text. I am programming for WP7, if that changed anything. It runs on a button click.

Below is my code:

```
 private void Draw()
    {
        Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

        number[0] = random.Next(0, 9);
        number[1] = random.Next(0, 9);
        number[2] = random.Next(0, 9);

            no1.Text = number[0].ToString();
            no2.Text = number[1].ToString();
            no3.Text = number[2].ToString();

        MessageBox.show("Example message");

    }
```

Comment: So what happens if you comment out the MessageBox?

Comment: The text is updated when the message box is displayed, or after you've closed it?

Comment: It will be because the phone is not getting any chance to update its screen until after the Draw() function has been exited I expect. You'll need to call Repaint or something before displaying the message box. Sorry I can't tell you exactly what as I haven't coded for windows phone yet. I'm sure someone else will be along soon with more info though ;)

Comment: What you describe makes no sense. There is no reason changing the Text property of a TextBox control would require you to display a MessageBox for the value to be updated.  Please post the code that calls **Draw()**

Comment: In reply to  @KooKiz, the text is updated as soon as I close the messagebox.

Comment: @Ramhound - it works fine and runs, but I am looking to include a messagebox after the text appears, but doing that causes the messagebox to appear before the text updates, if that makes sense. Code is below:

    private void btn_Spin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Draw();
        }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Russell Troywest pointed out, your code is executing on the UI thread, the very same thread that is in charge of updating the graphical interface. Therefore, the visual representation of the textbox won't be updated until your function exits.

A simple solution is to delay the execution of your messagebox:

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.show("Example message"));
```

This way, your `draw` method will exit without displaying the Message Box, then the UI thread will display it as soon as it's done refreshing the interface.